# Unable to load a shapefile with Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm try to load this shapefile with Basemap in order to plot it in Python:

http://geodata.gov.gr/en/dataset/periphereies-elladas/resource/7c80a2c1-93b7-4814-9fc4-245e775acaa6

But I get the following error:

> ```
> ValueError: shapefile must have lat/lon vertices - it looks like this one has vertices
> in map projection coordinates. You can convert the shapefile to geographic
> coordinates using the shpproj utility from the shapelib tools
> ```

I tried using `shpproj` or `ogr2ogr` as another answer in this site suggested, but for the life of me I can not figure out what parameters I should pass to those programs, as I have zero knowledge about GIS in general. So if anyone here could help me with the conversion command that would be great.

I am on Ubuntu and the code I'm using is pretty simple I guess:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
map = Basemap()

map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='#ddaa66',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawcoastlines()

map.readshapefile('periphereies/periphereies', 'periphereies')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Just to add to the previous answer `ogr2ogr` can be downloaded in ubuntu with the gdal-bin package
```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a projection file (*.prj) is attached to the shapefile (i.e. "GGRS87 / Greek Grid" aka EPSG:2100, source: [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](https://www.epsg-registry.org/)), we can easily transform it to WGS84 (EPSG:4326) using ogr2ogr without declaring the source SRS:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 periphereies_WGS84.shp periphereies.shp
```

where `periphereies_WGS84.shp` is the transformed shapefile.

Comment: Thanks, this works! The code only works with Python 2 (not 3), but this must be a problem with basemap